# Responsive HTML mailer

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries, mailer, responsiveness

Trying to create the pure responsive HTML mailer, but facing issue on those Email clients where media queries are not supported.

Adding below meta tag in all the Emailers:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

But in below mentioned unsupported email clients I cannot handle the mail content.
-Gmail app (iOS + Android)
-Inbox by Gmail app (iOS + Android)
-Gmail (Android Browser)

How other do this, please share your views.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check below link for your question

[link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978)

Gmail app are not support responsive designs

Answer (score 0):

I did this email templates [Email template1](http://pragmaoffshore.in/valuepic/) ,[Email template2](http://www.pragmaoffshore.in/fiteats/) and [Email template3](http://pragmaoffshore.in/zero-fees-creative/) .I did this using table. you can take the reference of it.hope it can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

They key to achieve reponsive behavior in mailers is to effeciently utilise markup you write, and not any meta tag. This includes:

1. percentage based width
2. Grouping two or more elements (*table, td*) in div
3. making use of max-width in inline stying with width as attribute (`<table style="max-width:600px" width="100%">`)

Take a look at one of my mailer I have made available : https://github.com/ShudhPandit/Mailers

Hope, it helps